# Can I have more than one event code under "this Workbook"

Tags: vba, excel

I have these 2 codes:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Value In Target.Columns
    Columns(Value.Column).ColumnWidth = 8.43
    Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit
Next Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This two pieces of code work fine but the thing is I can't make them work together these 2 codes should be place under "This Workbook" object in excel so I've been trying to come up with a way for this to work I do understand that you should only have one event code in a workbook but that there is a "workaround" it someone suggested the following:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Macro1(Target)
    Call Macro2(Target)
End Sub

Sub Macro1(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub Macro2(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Value In Target.Columns
    Columns(Value.Column).ColumnWidth = 8.43
    Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit
Next Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But it does not work none of the event are triggered so as I type nothing happens, I thought at first it would be impossible but when someone suggested this at first it made sense but it doesn't work but still I saw a shred of hope which I want to hang on tight to but since I don't know who to make it work.

Is it possible to have these 2 codes working on the same workbook?

Comment: I think in Macro2 you need to pass in `Sh object` as it references the object `Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit` from `sub Worksheet_Change`

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just gather all of your original code under a single Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange procedure? Also as part of your alternative, you switched to a worksheet event procedure - have you actually switched your code to the relevant place accordingly ie to your worksheet code modules?

Comment: @IAmDranged I have tried both things with no results the other problem is that if I change it to the sheet modules it will be only trigered at such sheet whereas I need the code to function in the entire Workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've tried this and for now its working

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Macro1(Target)
    Call Macro2(Target)
End Sub

Sub Macro1(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Target.Offset(-1, 0).Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Macro2(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Value In Target.Columns
    Columns(Value.Column).ColumnWidth = 8.43
    ActiveSheet.Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit
Next Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

These events need to be under the Sheet object, not the workbook.  Note that from the dropdown, when you are in the "thisWorkbook" code section, there is no "Change" event.  You'll also need to name the function `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: But still how would I be able to have both codes working at the same time? even if the code is in the SHeet object

Comment: They don't run simultaneously, but in sequence.  First Macro1 will run, then Macro2.

Comment: Let me me give it a go with the code I was suggested

Comment: I'm getting Runtime error '424' debug shows `Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit`

as the issue

Comment: A separate issue from the original question, but likely because the `.AutoFit` method must contain an entire column or entire row.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820840%28v=office.15%29.aspx Try `...Columns(Value.Column).EntireColumn.Autofit`

Comment: Debug a little bit and make a separate post.  When I run the single line `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Autofit` I get, as you would expect, an autofitted column.  Assuming `Value` has been set appropriately, you should be able to simply call `Value.Autofit`.  Check that `Value` and `Sh` are both set correctly.